# $scope variable not showing on frontend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am getting a variable by a $http.get followed by .then but when I want to use it in the frontend with {{ variable }} - it comes up as empty. I am using Angular 1.6.4.

I thought this was an async issue so I wrapped it around .then so it should now work.

**Controller**:

```
mainApp.controller('navBarController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function($scope, $http, $q){

$scope.profileID = '';

var getProfileID = function(){
    return $http.get('/session');
};

getProfileID().then(function(res) {
    console.log($scope.profileID = res.data.facebookProfileId);//this gives me the profileID as expected
    $scope.profileID = res.data.facebookProfileId;
});

}]);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="searchbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="navBarController">
    <li><a href="/profile#/profile{{ profileID }}">Profile</a></li><!--the profileID is empty here-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: have you tried debugging? putting random values on your `profileID` first to see if it's really an async issue?

Comment: Good idea and it isolates the issue to be not related to async - thanks. However, what the hell's going on? I will keep looking around but if you can think of something, shout away mate.

Comment: use `ng-href`, also print the value to console to make sure it's defined

Comment: Just used ng-href actually (realised that how Angular likes it from previous mistakes) and the result is still the same. Also, I am consoling it where the data is shown properly.... Really lost here

Comment: @ShayanKhan it should work really, where's your `ng-app`? initializing? is `facebookProfileId` not empty?

Comment: ng-app is at the very top tied to body. Also, facebookProfileId is not empty as I can console.log it

Comment: Code shown works fine here https://plnkr.co/edit/irPn8jgXq8sSzkcTL5O7?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks for that. In that case, I have hit a brick wall and don't know what I am doing wrong....

Comment: problem is clearly elsewhere in code or logic we can't see

Comment: Yeah. Will need to have a hard look at this again. Thanks anyway. I will keep this post updated if something comes out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because NodeJS uses {{ varName }} and so does Angular. So, in the initial app.js app, I just added:

```
app.locals.delimiters = '<% %>';
```

By the way, I was using the 'hogan-express' templating engine.

Hope this comes in handy to someone at some point. I was looking entirely in the wrong place.